# pip installed packages not in sys.path

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I'm a python noob. Have installed virtualenv and pip, and everything looks OK to me, but when trying to import packages installed through pip, python doesn't find them. I'm on OS X and have the system python 2.6 in `/usr/bin`, so installed 2.7 into `/usr/local/bin` via the package installer. When installing pip and virtualenv, I made sure the 2.7 python was being used by setting the PATH to have `/usr/local/bin` first.

```
(pysite)sbeam@pris ~/Sites]$ pip freeze
Django==1.4
Markdown==2.1.1
psycopg2==2.4.5
wsgiref==0.1.2

(pysite)sbeam@pris ~/Sites]$ echo $PYTHONPATH

(pysite)sbeam@pris ~/Sites]$ which python
/Users/sbeam/.virtualenvs/pysite/bin/python

(pysite)sbeam@pris ~/Sites]$ env | grep VIRTUAL
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME=.project
VIRTUAL_ENV=/Users/sbeam/.virtualenvs/pysite
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR=/Users/sbeam/.virtualenvs
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR=/Users/sbeam/.virtualenvs

(pysite)sbeam@pris ~/Sites]$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> pp(sys.path)
['',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>>> import markdown
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named markdown
```

Comment: When I want to make sure to use a Python version in my virtualenv, instead of fiddling with `PATH` I find it more useful to pass the path to the python executable through the `--python` flag: `virtualenv --python=/usr/local^Cin/python2.7 myenv` Have you tried it? I had a lot of PITA with Python in Mac OS and as far as I remember this was the only reliable solution.

Comment: I tried that flag in creating a new virtualenv and it made no difference

Comment: Dumb question, but did you install pip with Python 2.7?

Comment: Can you add the output of `which pip`?

Answer (score 0):

Note that by design and request new versions (1.7+) of `virtualenv` do not include `site-packages` from the system by default.

http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/news.html

You can explicitly use `--system-site-packages` on virtualenv creation see:

http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html#the-system-site-packages-option

Or you can just take the output of freeze and in the virtualenv do `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: ok, but the problem is that the pip-installed packages (eg, markdown) are not in `sys.path`, not that the system packages are not found. I tried creating a new virtualenv with the `--system-site-packages` flag, but it made no difference since I have not installed any packages globally.

Comment: Is your output all from the same shell session (and thus in the virutal env) - if you run `/Users/sbeam/.virtualenvs/pysite/bin/python` and inspect sys.path what do you get?